# AxiosError (Request failed with status code 400)

Tags: django, axios, react-redux

I have been following a React-Django tutorial. In addition to tutorial I was trying to store image using a post request via axios but getting a axios error 400. I am trying to make a post request using an action `Add_lead()` in my reducers.
This is my front-end:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { addLead } from '../../actions/leads';

class Form extends Component {
  
  //initial state 
  state = {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    message: '',
    gender: '', 
    image: null, 

  };

  
  static propTypes = {
    addLead: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  onChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.name === 'image') {
      this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.files[0] }); // Handle file input
    } else {
      this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }
  };
  

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, email, message, gender, image } = this.state;
    const lead = { name, email, message, gender, image };

    this.props.addLead(lead);
    this.setState({
      name: '',
      email: '',
      message: '',
      gender: '',
      image: null,
    });

    alert('Form submitted.');

  };


  render(){
  
    const { name, email, message, gender, image } = this.state;
    return (

      <div className="card card-body mt-4 mb-4">
        <h2>Add Lead</h2>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="text"
              name="name"
              onChange={this.onChange}
              value={name}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="email"
              name="email"
              onChange={this.onChange}
              value={email}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea
              className="form-control"
              type="text"
              name="message"
              onChange={this.onChange}
              value={message}
              required
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Gender</label>
            <select
              className="form-control"
              name="gender"
              onChange={this.onChange}
              value={gender}
              required
            >
              <option value="male">Male</option>
              <option value="female">Female</option>
              <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Image</label>
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="file"
              name="image"
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    
    )
  };


}

export default connect( null, { addLead } )(Form);
```

This is my addlead action:

```
// ADD LEAD
export const addLead = (lead) => (dispatch) => {
  console.log(lead) 
  axios
  .post('/api/leads/', lead)
  .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_LEAD,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));   
};
```

I did `console.log(lead)` inside the `addLead()` action.
This is the output of it

> {name: 'shuja', email: 'shuja@gmail.com', message: 'Hello Iam shuja', gender: 'male', image: File}

My backend is running fine. I am able to add leads in the Database through Django rest framework and show them on frontend even delete action is working fine.
This is the Get request on Django rest framework.

```json
[
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "shahood",
        "email": "shahood@gmail.com",
        "message": "hello I am Shahood",
        "gender": "Male",
        "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/leads_images/2021_03_30_21_01_IMG_5413.JPG",
        "created_at": "2023-08-13T21:09:52.246323Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "ahmed",
        "email": "ahmed@gmail.com",
        "message": "hello I am amy",
        "gender": "Male",
        "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/leads_images/New.png",
        "created_at": "2023-08-13T21:17:35.269783Z"
    }
]
```

Comment: do check the CSRF token, and errors related to it

Comment: I solved the gender selection problem. For the image i think its best to upload it on a cloud platform. Get the key and submit it in the database. This technique is much better I guess.